# Just installed Ubuntu on my Nexus 10... how do I get to a bash terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, ubuntu-touch

I just installed the Touch preview on my Nexus 10. It is not at all what I expected. I thought it would be just like my desktop; I'm not at all interested in the "experience"... all I want is a bash prompt :) Is this possible, or have I totally misconstrued what Canonical intended to provide?

Answer (score -3):

To my knowledge, a bash prompt is not included by default.